# Почему этот кусок кода выводит list index out of range?

Tags: python, selenium

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='listing-image']")
        ic(items)
        count = 1
        with open(f"Parse_{query}.txt", "w") as file:
            for i in items:
                i.click()
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
                time.sleep(1)
                print(f"{count} URL = {driver.current_url}")

                file.write(f"{count} " + driver.current_url + '\n')
                count += 1
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
                time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Это викторина такая? Конкурс на самый нелепый ответ? Если нет, то как мы должны догадаться по этому "куску кода", что у вас там происходит.  Вы даже трейс ошибки не приложили.

Comment: Проверяйте размер `driver.window_handles`, скорее всего там не было второго элемента, поэтому при `driver.window_handles[1]` возникла та ошибка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня, к несчастнью, была та же проблема, и дело в строке `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])`. Попробуйте увеличить значение `time.sleep(1)` до 10, то есть использование `time.sleep(10)` для ожидания загрузки другой веб–страницы решило эту проблему.